# how to do intervlan routing between two hosts in different subnet

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, layer3

how to do intervlan routing between two hosts in different subnet separated by two layer 3 switches & without using ip routing command & by using the concept of native vlan.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no common layer 2 connection between distinct VLANs they need to communicate through a layer 3 device - a router. If you don't want your L3 switches to route you require an additional router.

The native VLAN (of a trunk port) is the VLAN untagged traffic is associated with. This is unrelated to routing.

Edit: for a more specific answer you'll need to provide a more specific question: provide a network diagram, switch models, switch configurations and I'll update the answer.

Comment: i was asked this question by my mentor & she told me there Is a way to do that & she gave me a hint to use the concept of native vlan.

Comment: i have taken host a with ip address 192.168.10.1 which is connected to l3 switch wit fa0/1 interface & is in vlan 10 , the layer 3 switch is connected to another layer 3 switch wit interface fa0/2 & fa0/2 repectively & both its interfaces are in vlan 30 & are using ip address 10.1.1.1 & 10.1.1.2 respectively.the layer 3  switch is connected to host b with interface fa0/1 & is in vlan 20 with ip address 192.168.20.1 & i am providing static routes on both the switches. so is there a way to achieve this configuration but without using static routes.

Comment: You do need a router. You can point each node's default gateway to this router or use static routes. I still don't see the relation between inter-VLAN communication and native VLANs. PS: please add specific details to your question - nobody is going to read all the comments to figure out what you're asking.